# How to resume disconnected SSH X11-forwarded applications?

Tags: linux, ssh, x11-forwarding

I am happily using SSH's X11-forwarding to run some applications and then the connection was disconnected.

Running `ps ax` from a new SSH connection shows that the applications are still running. How do I "resume" or recover the GUI for the applications to prevent data lost?

Comment: related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/27843/redirect-existing-windows-via-ssh-and-x11-forwarding

Answer (score 2):

The successor of *XMove* is **Xpra**. you find the currently latest version here: http://xpra.org,
or as the `xpra` package in the package repositories.

I am currently checking it out myself, and it seems to work pretty well. At least performance wise, it appears to lag even less then the default X forwarding (as of summer 2014).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look into [XMove](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/x11/xmove).  I am not sure if this will work with a detached window, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: uhm, I cannot do `sudo apt-get install xmove` in my Lucid based Mint. The package is not there. Can you explain how to install it?

Comment: I would read over the [installation document](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/cgi-bin/wwwtar?/hpux/X11/Networking/xmove-2.0b2/xmove-2.0b2-src-11.00.tar.gz+xmove-2.0b2/HPUX.Install+text).  However it appears that the columbia ftp is down, so I am not sure how to grab the package. It appears that you can grab the package [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jaunty/+source/xmove/2.0beta2-8)